# How to populate ComboBoxes from ListBox selection?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

So I have a UserForm that has a ListBox and ComboBoxes.

I also have a button above the ListBox that when clicked, the data from the spreadsheet will be displayed.

If I clicked the value from the ListBox, it will be automatically displayed on the ComboBoxes below per column.

Say the value from the `Schema` column from the ListBox says "ABC", "ABC" will also be displayed on the ComboBox below it. It is the same with the other ComboBoxes.

[image]

Is there a possible way to do it?

I've been looking for answers but none of the methods have worked on me and I couldn't find any similar problems. Please help :(

Comment: Yes, there is. But I see no sense in these ComboBoxes. Why are these ComboBoxes and not TextBoxes?

Comment: Hello, I considered it to be comboboxes so if the user adds/edit a row, they won't fill it up by typing. They would just select from the combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a sub on Click event and then select one by one the columns

```
Private Sub <ListBox>_Click()

<ComboBox>.Value = <Userform>.<ListBox>.Column(0)

End Sub
```

Replace the < name > with the actual name of your objects

But as PEH said, I see no reason why this case would be a ComboBox, you may want to consider changing it for a TextBox

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I've been looking for answers everywhere but none worked. This was very simple. You saved me thanksss!!!!!!